# How to add items Slick grid to Multi select TextBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slickgrid

I am new to Slick Grid.
This is my javascript code,I declared my variables here,

```
var grid;
var printPlugin;
var dataView;
var data = [];
var selectdItems = [];
var columns = [
       { id: "Id", name: "Id", field: "Id", sortable: true },
       { id: "Name", name: "Name", field: "Name", sortable: true, cssClass: "cell-title", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, width: 300 },
       { id: "Addr", name: "Addr", field: "Addr", sortable: true, editor: Slick.Editors.Text }
       ];
```

I add check box here,By using this check box, I want to add those items to 'selectdItems' array

```
        var checkboxSelector = new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn({
              cssClass: "slick-cell-checkboxsel"
               });
columns.push(checkboxSelector.getColumnDefinition());
```

Those are my options

```
var options = {
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        enableColumnReorder: false,
        multiColumnSort: true,
        editable: true,
        ebableAddRow: true,
        asyncEditorLoading: true,
        autoEdit: false
      };
```

This is my ajax method to getting data.In this ajax method I written '$('#btnShift').click(function (e)){}' function,If I written this method out side the ajax method it is not working,If I written this function in ajax method The ajax method is calling every action in a page, When I am adding selected records to multiline textbox those items binding and again rebinding the data to grid and clear the multiline textbox

```
  var param = {};
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'AllFeatures.aspx/method',
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (resp) {
        var v = resp;
        for (i = 0; i < resp.d.length; i++) {
            data[i] = {
                Id: resp.d[i].split('~')[0],
                Name: resp.d[i].split('~')[1],
                Addr: resp.d[i].split('~')[2],
            };
        }
        grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
        var argRows = [];
        grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            argRows = args.rows;
        });
        grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({ selectActiveRow: false }));
        grid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector);
        var columnpicker = new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(columns, grid, options);

  $('#btnShift').click(function (e) {
      var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
      dataView.beginUpdate();
      dataView.getItems().length = 0;
      dataView.endUpdate();
  for (var i = 0; i < argRows.length; i++) {
             selectdItems.push(data[argRows[i]]);
             data.splice(argRows[i], 1);
         $('#sel').append('<option>' + data[argRows[i]]['Name'] + '</option')
}
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
e.priventDefault();
  });
    }

});
```

I want to when I select the check box in grid after click the shift method that check box selected data shifted to multiline textbox.(I don't want to call ajax method multiple times )

This is my HTML Code

```
 <div id="myGrid" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;" class="item-details-editor-container" ></div>
 <button data-action='save' id="btnShift">shift</button>
  <select multiple="" id="sel"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do without a mockup.

But have you seen the examples at the 6pac repo:
https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples

eg: 
http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-select2-multiselect-editor.html